# how can i pass template class which take parameter pack to other template class as a parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

I have something like that:

```
template<int ... args>
class X{};
```

and  want to pass that class as parameters to 2nd template class.
Now I have:

```
template<class X<int... args1> el1, class X<int... args2> el2>
class Y{};
```

Compiler is throwing errors `Pack expansion does not contain any unexpanded parameter packs`to me and i don't really know what can i do...I have tried lot of possible order of `int` `...` and `args`, but it is still not working. How may i make it work?

I want to make such piece of code compiling

```
Y<X<1,2>,X<3,4>> el;
```

Comment: please include the error in the question

Comment: You can just do `template<class el1, class el2> class Y{}` if you just want to use class name and not the template arguments.

Comment: i need acces to args

Comment: Please edit you question with a use case, i.e. how you want to use this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [template template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), which have the following syntax:

```
template<template <int... args1> typename el1, 
         template <int... args2> typename el2>
class Y{};
```

Note that pre-c++17, you have to use the keyword `class` instead of `typename` here.

Comment: but i want to specify that template to take only paramaters made from class X, is it possible?

Comment: @MichałOlbrychtowicz I'm not sure what you mean by "parameters made from class X". Could you edit your question with some specific use case? i.e. How do you want to *use* `X` and `Y`?

Comment: done, i mean that i want class Y taking paramatres only made from class X and your example lets class Y take two parameter of any class, which use integer parameter pack inside

Comment: Ok, that may be doable, but this really sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you share what you want to *do* with this template? Show your use case, you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: it is not necessary, just my whim. I was just curious if i can do it in that why. I have already succeeded in way which you wrote as answer :)